# How do I compile gwget from source?

Tags: software-installation, compiling

I extracted the source, opened the terminal, moved to source directory
and ran the following command:

```
sudo ./configure
```

Error: command not found!
what is wrong with it?

Comment: What command was not found? Have you yet ... `sudo apt-get install build-essential`?

Comment: i'm new in Linux, whats first steps to compile a source? what should i do whit apt-get?

Comment: The basic building blocks are in the package, build-essential. If you install it, then the commands that configure uses will be available. Then, the configure command will let you know what other programs or libraries may be required to build the program.

Comment: Sounds like there isn't a `configure` script. Not every package uses configure, make, make install. What package is this?

Comment: i used sudo apt-get install build-essential and it downloaded , but still the same error

Comment: its bluefish text editor i used this package as a test for compiling, in the directory there is a configure file but i dont know why it says command not found!

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, don't do `sudo su` or `sudo ./configure`. You can build as your user.

I assume you are building bluefish from SVN, and thus don't have a `configure` script. You can create it by running `./autogen.sh`, as described on http://bluefish.openoffice.nl/development.html.

```
svn co https://bluefish.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/bluefish/trunk/bluefish
cd bluefish
./autogen.sh
./configure
make 
sudo make install
```

Comment: thanks i just used bluefish as an example to compile coz i could not compile anything, now i tried another program "gwget", and took screen shot ,i gives another error

Comment: OK, now it looks like you don't have a C compiler installed. Install `build-essential`, and everything else gwget requires (see it's `README` / `INSTALL` file)

Answer (score 1):

First you should extract the contents of the *.tar.gz file in a directory. 
Read instructions in the INSTALL file, which gives you detailed instructions how to do it.

For "some" software you want to install the following method works:
1. extract the archive into a directory
2. cd to that directory
3. ./configure (add "--prefix=/usr" if you want to install it in /usr)
4. make 
5. sudo make install

That is all to it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to first install build-essential:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Afterward, configure should alert you to any other programs or libraries that are required to compile the software.

Comment: now i installed build-essential using : sudo apt-get build essential, and it downloaded! but still same problem exist

Comment: Just this: `./configure` Save the sudo for `sudo make install` after compilation succeeds.

Comment: In fact you are running as root - so sudo not required.

Comment: ams might be on to it... or try `bash ./configure`

Comment: i tried sudo bash +x ./configure and it worked somehow but another error happened in last line, i took screen shot please see it

Comment: Okay, what's really going on? Look in "config.log" to see if you can glean the exact error - toward the end of the log.

Comment: i dont really know, i've uploaded config.log file here , please check it if possible ,thank you dude http://up5.iranblog.com/images/5pkynbwogufy9r38u1uj.zip

Comment: You are having far too much trouble. This problem looks like the same as before: permissions. See your log file: `configure:3020: ./a.out ./configure: line 3021: ./a.out: Permission denied` What file system does the media drive use, and is it mounted `noexec`? I think you should download the source tarball again as a regular user, and then extract it in your home directory. Then give it a whirl. :)

Answer (score 0):

to compile a program from source, unpack the archive as follows:

```
tar -xf fooprog.tar
```

then go into the unpacked directors (usually same name):

```
cd fooprog
```

in this folder as first step invoke:

```
./configure
```

Not all programs come with a configure script but many. Read the README or INSTALL file which is usually in the archive for more information.

After configure succeeded, proceed with:

```
make
```

and if that also succeeded install the software with:

```
sudo make install
```

Usually you only need to invoke this last step as superuser (sudo)

If configure fails you should look at the output and install all the packages it requires, especially also build-essential the way, christopher recommended.

Comment: i used sudo apt-get install build-essential and it downloaded, but still it says command not found

Comment: mitser user seven... if you do not add the complete output we cannot help you.please copy and paste all steps from the console window into your initial posting. do not leave anything out!!!  Further you can check what files exist in the archive.After unpacking just invoke ls in the unpacked archive. If there is no configure file then you cannot invoke it.You could also tell us, which software you try to install.

Comment: Dear Mickael K ,sorry for that , i'm not so familiar with linux but i took a screen shot you can see here what i've done and program is bluefish as you can see its name in path http://up5.iranblog.com/images/ierm22w9cbgnv3jcmkp4.png

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "configure" exists, this message can mean that something referenced *by* the file was missing.

Try this:

```
bash +x ./configure
```

If it still doesn't work, post (some of) the output (edit your question above).

Comment: thank you it worked , but still in the last line it says another error, i took screen shot and put it above please tell me what does it mean?